# Internal resistance of LDo

Tags: internal-resistance

I was trying to measure the internal resistance of an LDO that will produce 2.85V. I used a Digital multimeter to do this, but I got a resistance of 810 Ohm and the LDO can support upto 450 mA. Will the internal resistance of the LDO can be that high?

Comment: how are you measuring the internal resistance? ... note: should really refer to the device by its correct name "LDO regulator"

Comment: ...and what do you plan to do wit this value once you have it?

Comment: "Internal resistance" isn't a proper parameter of an LDO. You can determine **output resistance** though.

Comment: What is LDo? The 'o'  in lowercase on purpose?

Comment: LDOs with only a few hundred milliVolts of input-output differential voltage will be operating the internal Pchannel MOSFET in "triode" mode, where the FET is nearly a pure resistor that is varied to control the I*R voltage drop. Apply a sinusoidal current from a function generator at 1,000 Hz thru 1Kohm resistor and 100uF capacitor. Watch the polarity. Compute the AC current injected into the LDO output. Use a scope to measure the AC voltage on the LDO output. You can compute the output resistance of the LDO, which depends on servo-amp bandwidth, and properties of the Pchan FET.

Comment: LDO stand for a Low dropout voltage regulator. I like to check the Thevenin's rule is applicable in the LDO.

Answer (score 2):

If the input supply voltage to an "ideal" 5 volt regulator is 10 volts and the output load is 10 ohms (0.5 amp output current), then the regulator will "act" like a 10 ohm resistor in order to facilitate 5 volts at the output. It's just a simple potential divider.

If the load changes rapidly between 9 ohms and 11 ohms, then the regulator (due to feedback control), will keep the output voltage at 5 volts by rapidly altering its effective series resistance to counter the changing load impedance and current. So, when the load is at 9 ohms, the regulator will act like a 9 ohm resistor in order to keep the output at 5 volts.

If the input voltage reduces to (say) 8 volts and the load is 10 ohms then the effective series resistance of the regulator has to be 3 volts/0.5 amp = 6 ohm.

The effective series resistance of an ideal voltage regulator will change slowly or rapidly to counter the load and input voltage circumstances it faces.

Comment: Thank you, I got it the output impedance will vary with load.

Comment: The effective series-pass resistance will vary with both load resistance and input voltage (to be precise).